# How to store incoming request in case of Akka Clustering?

Tags: java, akka, akka-stream, akka-http, akka-cluster

I am using Akka for Java and have enabled Akka Clustering. Now, I am sending request to the main Akka server from another Akka agent in another Java application - thanks to clustering.

Is there any way to store these incoming requests in the main Akka server?

Comment: Do not get the point, need more explanation. Akka server is a http server? Why do you want to store the incoming request?

Comment: It is not an HTTP server. Just an Akka node (in the cluster) that I am referring to as the "main" Akka server.

Comment: These requests are objects. It is easy to store or cache then in Akka server. I do not know what is the problem?

Comment: Can you clarify the use-case?  When you say, "I am sending a request.. from another Akka agent in another Java application", what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Can you elaborate your use case so that we understand what you are trying to achieve? If you are referring to just storing messages sent to the main node (calling it server is actually misleading), that has to be done manually. One option is to make that main node a persistent actor (but evaluate whether the node represents a stateful domain entity or not). Another option would be to store the message in DB manually. Or better, delegate this job of "storing" to another actor.